# How can I get the pixel data corresponding to a shapefile with some coordinates' points in IDL?

Tags: coordinates, pixel, idl-programming-language

What I want to get is the pixel's data corresponding to these points in the vector file. And add the maximum values arround the pixel in a window of 8 to the coordinate as a new value. I am a newcomer to IDL, how can I solve the problems ? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what pixel data you're referring to, so I'll assume it's another array which you can index with the shapefile coordinates.  Perhaps [this article](http://www.idlcoyote.com/code_tips/extractpoly.php) will help you to extract the vertices of the polygon (looks like you'll have to cough up a bit of cash for the routine he uses to do so).  If you want to get the maximum values around each pixel, after you get each `x` and `y` vector to index into the data (`pixel` below) you'll have to do some [dimensional juggling](http://www.idlcoyote.com/tips/rebin_magic.html).  Something like the following might work, but I haven't tested it (you'll probably have to play with the dimension over which the maximum is calculated):

```
n = n_elements(x)
; pixel = findgen(np, np)

; Make a copy of "pixel" so we can eliminate the center element
; from consideration of the maximum
new_pixel = pixel
new_pixel[x, y] = new_pixel[x + 1, y + 1]

x = rebin(reform(x, n, 1), n, 9)
y = rebin(reform(y, n, 1), n, 9)

x += rebin(reform([-1, 0, 1], 1, 3), n, 9)
y += rebin(reform(rebin(reform([-1, 0, 1], 3, 1), 3, 3), 1, 9), n, 9)

; Get surrounding elements
new_pixel = new_pixel[x, y]
; Get maximum
max_pixel = max(new_pixel, dimension=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using QGIS for shapefile operations before importing the matrix indices into IDL. Then you can perform a simple calculation:

output = input[where(index eq shp_value)]

To align the pixels, I would write the shapefile values to an existing raster when creating the index raster in QGIS. I believe you want the [Rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/rasterize.html) tool. For more information, read my [reply](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.idl-pvwave/4E5kR9DxybQ) regarding zonal statistics.

Cheers,

Adam